# OO Design: use Properties or Overloaded methods?

Tags: delphi, oop

Question about OO design.

Suppose I have a base object vehicle.  And two descendants: truck and automobile.

Further, suppose the base object has a base method:

```
Procedure FixFlatTire(); abstract;
```

When the truck and automobile override the base object's, they require different information from the caller.

Am I better off overloading FixFlatTire like this in the two descendant objects:

```
Procedure Truck.FixFlatTire( OfficePhoneNumber: String;
                             NumberOfAxles: Integer): Override; Overload;

Procedure Automobile.FixFlatTire( WifesPhoneNumber: String;
                                  AAAMembershipID: String): Override; Overload;
```

Or introducing new properties in each of the descendants and then setting them before calling FixFlatTire, like this:

```
Truck.OfficePhoneNumber := '555-555-1212';
Truck.NumberOfAxles := 18;
Truck.FixFlatTire();

Automobile.WifesPhoneNumber := '555-555-2323';
Automobile.AAAMembershipID  := 'ABC';
Automobile.FixFlatTire();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with properties is pointless.  You can't use polymorphism properly since the functions take different parameters.  You should just have distinct methods in the subclasses with the appropriate parameters.

Now, if you come back with a more complex version in which you only hold a reference to the base class then a different design would be called for, but it would be neither of the ones you have offered so far.

Comment: "You can't use polymorphism properly since the functions take different parameters." Ah ha!  That's what I realize was bothering me I realize now that you spelled it out, David! (Prematurely posted this comment by hitting the <Enter>-key.)  The code that uses this design is going to have to know which descendant its working with, so there's no advantage to preserving the method's signature by using properties.  Thanks for articulating this for me.

Comment: I don't necessarily think the property approach is _correct_, but why is it pointless?  If you know the class will have the properties necessary to perform the operation FixFlatTire, then each descendant class could implement a argument-free FixFlatTire() method.

Comment: @Larry @Robert It's pointless because there is no advantage, and many disadvantages, when contrasted with the two separate methods approach. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: @David (FYI, I'm not the downvoter, just trying to learn something).  I tend to agree with the method approach, but if the arguments are in fact properties of the entity being modeled I could also argue that they should be made properties of the class itself.

Answer (score 5):

If the data in question are logically part of the descendant class (if you might use them in other contexts) it makes sense to add the properties directly to the descendant class.

If they apply strictly to the FixFlatTire method, it makes more sense to specify them as arguments to that function.

If you supply a different method signature in a descendant class, that is not (to my knowledge) a case of overloading.  You are simply overriding the original function with a new function with different arguments.  Overloading is when two identically named functions are available, distinguished by different signatures.

[Edit]

Looking at your arguments a bit closer, here are some more thoughts:

- NumberOfAxles pretty clearly seems to be a property of TTruck.
- PhoneNumber and AAAMembershipID seem to me to be properties of a class you don't have yet, TOwner (with possible descendant classes TCorporateOwner and TIndividualOwner).  Then, a TOwner reference can become a property of TVehicle or an argument to FixFlatTire() (although I imagine it would better belong as a property of the TVehicle).

Answer (score 3):

The real error is

```
FixFlatTire(); abstract;
```

It certainly should be

```
FixFlatTire(); virtual; abstract;
```

to enable polymorphic behavior.

You should not overload virtual methods, only override preserving method's arguments.

---

**Update**

You should not and can not overload virtual methods. The following code does not even compile:

```
type
  TVehicle = class
    procedure FixFlatTire(); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TTruck = class(TVehicle)
    Procedure FixFlatTire( OfficePhoneNumber: String;
                             NumberOfAxles: Integer); Override; Overload;
  end;

  TAutomobile = class(TVehicle)
    Procedure FixFlatTire( WifesPhoneNumber: String;
                               AAAMembershipID: String); Override; Overload;
  end;
```

You should preserve virtual method's arguments while overriding the virtual method.

So the answers is - the first option (overloading) is just impossible.

Comment: Agreed: that's an error, Serg.  But, having fixed that, my question remains as to whether I should pass the necessary information via properties, or via 2 methods with different parameters.

Comment: @Robert via two methods with different parameters, state used to pass parameters is truly evil, in my view

Comment: Not to say that overloading is the correct option here, but what you say is not correct.  It IS possible to overload virtual functions.  The reason your example doesn't compile is that there are no inherited overloaded virtual methods (with matching signatures) for the overRIDE directives to apply to.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the latter, as it's easy for someone to set some properties and forget to later call the method. The first is a problem too though, because you don't have a matching signature for each method in the base class.

Most problems in OOP can be solved with another layer of abstraction. You could have something like this in the base class, shared by both Automobile and Truck.

```
procedure FixFlatTire(TireProvider: ITireProvider); abstract; virtual;
```

ITireProvider can be subclassed with an OfficeTireProvider and AAATireProvider, which contain the respective properties you need to set for each, and they can override any members of ITireProvider needed to do the actual tyre fixing.